# How to automate putty from java

Tags: java, putty

Is there any way so that i can automate putty from java class including running,login and sending unix commands one by one to executeand.

I have a some specific command list that i wan't to execute on server for that i wan't to automate putty.

Comment: How about using an ssh library for Java like http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=ssh+java This doesn't use putty.

Comment: How will the connection be made? SSH? Telnet? For telnet, it's literally as easy as opening a socket... for SSH, you'd be better off using an SSH library in your app.

Comment: @peter, got any personal recommendations to add to the plain google search?

Answer (score 4):

You do not want to run putty as it expects a GUI environment which is not available when launched from Java.

You need a suitable ssh library which can handle the connection and send commands and received responses.  This allow you to fully script it from inside java.

I have heard good things about jsch - http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/ - but have not used it myself.

Comment: Indeed, JSch is the way. Also notice there is a bunch of higher-level users of Jsch (a few are named in their "applications using Jsch". To my mind, to simply run commands, it would be easier to use an abstraction layer, as using Jsch requires one to open streams and send/receive characters directly from thoses streams.

Answer (score 1):

maybe you could automate it at command line level, using [expectj](http://expectj.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to write a .bat file which will have your putty login details and then a text file which will have your commands. Then you could run that .bat file which will open putty and run all the commands you have in the list.

But, after doing all this my requirement has changed to having a independent GUI to manage my server, so I would agree with Ravn Anderson but that would take a lot of effort.

So it all depends what sort of application you need.